# Dropbox selective sync

Tags: dropbox

I have Ubuntu 19.04 and app from Dropbox v80.4.126
Everything with Dropbox desktop app had worked without any problems, until force restart during uploading some files.
After force restart Selective Sync window stopped showing up.
I'm clicking this button, and nothing happens

[image]

I have tried reinstall app according to official instructions

https://help.dropbox.com/en-en/installs-integrations/desktop/advanced-reinstall

but this didn't help. Maybe You have any idea how to force selective sync window to appear?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than just reinstalling Dropbox, you could try [Unlinking and Relinking](https://help.dropbox.com/accounts-billing/settings-sign-in/unlink-relink-computer-mobile) your account.

If the Selective Sync button is still not not working after that, you can exclude the folder(s) you don't want to sync to your device by using the command line.

From the command line `dropbox help exclude` will give you the options.

> dropbox exclude [list]
>
> dropbox exclude add [DIRECTORY] [DIRECTORY] ...
>
> dropbox exclude remove [DIRECTORY] [DIRECTORY] ...
>
> "list" prints a list of directories currently excluded from syncing.
>   "add" adds one or more directories to the exclusion list, then
>   resynchronizes Dropbox. 
>   "remove" removes one or more directories from
>   the exclusion list, then resynchronizes Dropbox.
>   With no arguments,
>   executes "list".
>
> Any specified path must be within Dropbox.

Therefore, open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/dropbox

dropbox exclude add ~/dropbox/YOURFOLDER
```

and then confirm your actions with

```
dropbox exclude list
```

A list of excluded folders will appear:

```
Excluded: ../../../root/Dropbox/YOURFOLDER
```